# macOS Mojave update messup with php CLI

Tags: php, macos, path, command-line-interface

I've updated my mac and now my php loaded at `http://localhost/`

index.php: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` says: `PHP Version 7.1.23`

However my CLI says different:

php -v `PHP 5.6.28 (cli)`

which php `/usr/local/bin/php`

echo $PATH
`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I know I need to add to $PATH not match the newer installation which is 7.1.23 but where is the new php binary ?

Anyone Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Ditto question](https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php)

Answer (score 0):

never mind I just removed the `/usr/local/bin`  from the path and now path:

echo $PATH
`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

php -v PHP 7.1.23 (cli) match build in php